# Get grand total of Total's textbox using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have many `textboxes` in a form where I am inserting `numeric values` and getting total of all the fields. There are 4 total `textboxes` and 1 grandtotal `textbox`. Currently I am able to get all the total textboxes values but, I am confused how to get sum of all the total `textbox` values in the **Grand total textbox** using Jquery or javascript.

Here is my html and js in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dL9bj0at/)

Do let me know how to do this

Comment: Not sure but, I think disabled = disabled fortotal field is problematic.

Comment: You can trigger a function on `change` event of input fields. This function would get the respective input values, sum them up and put the final result in the respective total box.

Comment: How can you write a `onkeypress` event on a disabled field?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value of the textbox to the result of adding the other values:

```
document.getElementById("grand-textbox-id").value = value1 + value2 + value3;
```

If you want to make it do it automatically, add a `change` event handler to all the inputs:

```
var calculateSum = function() {
    document.getElementById("grand-textbox-id").value = value1 + value2 + value3;
};
document.getElementById("input-1").onchange = calculateSum;
document.getElementById("input-2").onchange = calculateSum;
document.getElementById("input-3").onchange = calculateSum;
```

Comment: `value?` should be replaced by `parseFloat(value?)` otherwise the result will be a concatenated string rather than the sum of the values

Comment: @Phugo In the fiddle the OP is already using `parseInt`. Also, separation of concerns means that the conversion should take place outside the function, not inside.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".total").keyup(function(){
   var first=0,second=0,third=0,fourth=0;
   if($("#text1").val()!="")
   {
  
      first=$("#text1").val();
   }
   if($("#text2").val()!="")
   {
    
      second=$("#text2").val();
   }
   if($("#text3").val()!="")
   {
   
      third=$("#text3").val();
   }
   if($("#text4").val()!="")
   {
    
      fourth=$("#text4").val();
   }
   $("#grand").val( parseInt(first)+ parseInt(second)+ parseInt(third)+ parseInt(fourth));   
   
});
});
</script>

<style tupe="text/css">
.total
{
}
</style>


First val <input type="text" class="total" id="text1" value="" /><br />
second val <input type="text" class="total" id="text2" value="" /><br />
Third val <input type="text" class="total" id="text3" value="" /><br />
Fourth val <input type="text" class="total" id="text4" value="" /><br />
Grand val <input type="text" class="" id="grand" value="" readonly />
```